# Python ElementTree writing multiple namespaces

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML document which I am reading and appending to using ElementTree.
This has multiple namespaces declared. From what I can tell, ElementTree will only allow a single global namespace to be declared:

`ET.register_namespace(prefix, uri)`

I would like to write multiple namespaces out in the resulting file. If I try to manually append them using
`root.set(prefix, uri)`
Then they are put in the wrong order, and I get `cElementTree.ParseError: unbound prefix: line 2, column 0`

Edit: it turns out that I had a typo in the option I was setting. I corrected this, and it re-parses fine. So it looks like this is a viable solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add more code to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not restricted to just using the standard library, I suggest you install and use the [lxml](http://lxml.de) package which provides the `ElementTree` API, and it has a number of [advantages](http://lxml.de/intro.html), including easily allowing you to have multiple [namespaces](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) in the same document.